# How do I force a package sub-dependency version - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I will try to illustrate my problem in simple terms.

I want to install two plugins, `plugin A` in version 2.0 and `plugin B` in version 3.0 . `plugin B` has `plugin A` as a sub-dependency with a different version, and that version breaks the build phase of my react application.

Package A@2.0.0

Package B@2.0.0 ---> Package A @3.0.0 (one of the sub-dependencies)

My question is how do I force plugin B to install plugin A with the specified version, or not install it altogether?

Here's my package.json

```js
//my package.json
{
  "package A": "2.0.0",
  "package B": "2.0.0",
  "overrides": {
    "package B": {
      "package A": "2.0.0" //I try to force version 2 but it doesn't work
  }
}
```

Some things I tried or noticed:
Overrides doesn't seem to work on nested dependencies, maybe it works when you try to upgrade, or it's just not possible with the specific package I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I'm using yarn and all I had to do is put "resolutions" instead of "overrides"
Now my package json looks like this

```js
//my package.json
{
  "package A": "2.0.0",
  "package B": "2.0.0",
  "resolutions": {
    "package A": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```